# How rename or remap key in ansible

Tags: ansible, yaml, certbot

I'm trying to use [this repo](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-certbot) of **geerlingguy** (thx guy!) with my actual stuff
**but** the variables are not the same in my files and can't change them because their are used by others tasks...
My structure is actually like that:

```
apache2:
  vhost:
  - name: toto.com
    add_vhost: true
    add_ssl: true
  - name: AAA.toto.com
    add_vhost: true
    add_ssl: true
  - name: BBB.toto.com
    add_vhost: true
    add_ssl: true
  - name: CCC.toto.com
    add_vhost: true
    add_ssl: true
```

I duplicate this task for use my variables ([source](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-certbot/blob/master/tasks/main.yml)) but my variable is called `cert_item.name`
and I have to translate to `cert_item.domains` for tasks [in this file](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-certbot/blob/master/tasks/create-cert-standalone.yml) working.

```
- include_tasks: create-cert-standalone.yml
  with_items:
  - "{{ apache2.vhost }}"
  when:
  - certbot_create_if_missing
  - certbot_create_method == 'standalone'
  - cert_item_apache2.add_ssl | d(true)
  loop_control:
    loop_var: cert_item
```

how can I pass `cert_item.name` to the task and he read it `cert_item.domains` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the list certbot_certs before to include the tasks create-cert-standalone.yml

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    certbot_create_if_missing: true
    certbot_create_method: "standalone"
    apache2:
      vhost:
        - name: toto.com
          add_vhost: true
          add_ssl: true
        - name: AAA.toto.com
          add_vhost: true
          add_ssl: true
        - name: BBB.toto.com
          add_vhost: true
          add_ssl: true
        - name: CCC.toto.com
          add_vhost: true
          add_ssl: true

  tasks:

    - name: SET_FACTS | Populate attribute domains
      vars:
        certbot_entry: "{{ item.name }}"
      set_fact:
        certbot_certs: "{{ certbot_certs |default([]) + [certbot_entry] }}"
      loop: "{{ apache2.vhost }}"
      when:
        - certbot_create_if_missing
        - certbot_create_method == 'standalone'
        - item.add_ssl | d(true)


    - include_tasks: create-cert-standalone.yml
      with_items: "{{ certbot_certs }}"
      when:
        - certbot_create_if_missing
        - certbot_create_method == 'standalone'
      loop_control:
        loop_var: cert_item
```

my create-cert-standalone.yml file:

```yaml
---
- name: "Create cert standalone {{ cert_item }}"
  debug:
     msg: "{{ cert_item }}"
```

and here the output:

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************

TASK [SET_FACTS | Populate attribute domains] *******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'toto.com', 'add_vhost': True, 'add_ssl': True})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'AAA.toto.com', 'add_vhost': True, 'add_ssl': True})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'BBB.toto.com', 'add_vhost': True, 'add_ssl': True})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'CCC.toto.com', 'add_vhost': True, 'add_ssl': True})

TASK [include_tasks] *******************************************************************************
included: /mnt/c/Users/tonip/ansible_test_yaml/create-cert-standalone.yml for localhost
included: /mnt/c/Users/tonip/ansible_test_yaml/create-cert-standalone.yml for localhost
included: /mnt/c/Users/tonip/ansible_test_yaml/create-cert-standalone.yml for localhost
included: /mnt/c/Users/tonip/ansible_test_yaml/create-cert-standalone.yml for localhost

TASK [Create cert standalone toto.com] *******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "toto.com"
}

TASK [Create cert standalone AAA.toto.com] *******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "AAA.toto.com"
}

TASK [Create cert standalone BBB.toto.com] *******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "BBB.toto.com"
}

TASK [Create cert standalone CCC.toto.com] *******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "CCC.toto.com"
}
```

Comment: Your answer with "set_fact" help me well !

Comment: Very nice use of facts! Was exactly what I was looking for.